# Cordova Emulate Over Wifi

Tags: android, cordova, android-virtual-device

So i want to emulating my Cordova application to real android device that connected over wifi network, i've been following this blog https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root and it's work if i am using Android studio, because my devices is on the list of available AVDs.

And if i am using AVD, i can run this command successfully:

```
cordova emulate android --target=NEXUS4_API22
```

What cordova cli should i use? something like cordova emulate android --target=192.168.0.100:5555

Comment: make sure your device and android studio sharing the same network.

Comment: yes, it is on the same network, and i've already told that it works on android studio, i just need cordova command to call my android phone